# Wipe Unused Disc Space

Tags: linux

For security reasons I want to wipe the unused disk space on my storage media. How do I do that?
In other words, I want my unused disk space to be replaced with zeroes.

Comment: There are a ton of ways to do this sort of thing, and a pretty good start is already located [here](https://superuser.com/questions/19326/how-to-wipe-free-disk-space-in-linux). I'd say pick the method that suits your needs best.

Comment: Please add hardware (disk) info - HDD / SSD?

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/clear-unused-space-with-zeros-ext3-ext4/44236#44236 ?

Comment: Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44725/117549 for btrfs

Comment: You're right. What would be the best method for a SSD though?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear unused space with zeros (ext3,ext4)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/clear-unused-space-with-zeros-ext3-ext4)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Unix utility called `zerofree` to do exactly that.

---

Sources:

- [Debian man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/zerofree/zerofree.8.en.html)
- [Ubuntu man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/zerofree.8.html)