# remove unallocated space from a partition image

Tags: filesystems, backup, disk-usage

I have just created an image of an sd card using dd and the image is compressing down less than expected. I suspect this is because the card had not been zeroed out before I started to make the image. Is there a way to clear out "junk" stored on an image without having to start from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to zero out unused space is to mount the image, fill up the space with zeroes, and remove the zero-filled file.

```
mount -o loop /path/to/image /mnt
cat /dev/zero >/mnt/zero
rm /mnt/zero
umount /mnt
```

Depending on what the filesystem is, there may be tools that can work directly on the image. See [this question for ext2/ext3/ext4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/clear-unused-space-with-zeros-ext3-ext4) (answer: [zerofree](http://intgat.tigress.co.uk/rmy/uml/sparsify.html)).