# Purpose of /dev/zero?

Tags: filesystems

I tried to `cat /dev/zero`, and it didn't seem to do anything. I googled `/dev/zero`, and it says it's basically a blank file with infinite size. Is `cat` printing an infinite number of non-existent characters? How does this work? How does it provide infinite data if it's 0 bytes? What are the uses of this file, if one can simply create a blank file?

Comment: Run `cat -v /dev/zero` to see what it is doing. See [Clear unused space with zeros (ext3,ext4)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/clear-unused-space-with-zeros-ext3-ext4) for a common purpose.

Comment: There is also [/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) which behaves like an empty file if you want to read it and as a black hole if you write to it.

Comment: @jofel but you can't use /dev/null for infinite 0-bits, right? `cat foo > /dev/null` and `cat foo > /dev/zero` are the same, but `cat /dev/null` and `cat /dev/zero` aren't the same, correct?

Comment: @tkbx yes, correct. `/dev/null` returns immediately [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) if a program wants to read from it. `/dev/zero` returns infinitely 0-bytes.

Answer (score 62):

`/dev/zero` is a special file (in this case, a pseudo-device) that provides an endless stream of null characters (so hex 0x00)? That's why your `cat` is not outputting anything (but try running it through `od` (octal dump)).

'blank file with infinite size' is not 100% correct: it's not a regular file, but a special file (more like a 'stream' or a generator). You can read as much from it as you want, for example with `dd` (like `dd if=/dev/zero of=yourfile count=1024 bs=1024`).

It's not really a *blank* file, nor used to create blank files: it's used to create files or memory pages filled with only zeroes. You can also write to it, making it perform like a sinkhole (its more popular brother `/dev/null` is more commonly used for this though).

Comment: Why would someone want to fill up blank space, though?

Comment: For example, to erase what was there before. Or when transmitting.

Comment: does `srm` use this?

Comment: I've not read the `srm` manual or source, but most 'secure erasers' prefer to write (pseudo-)random data instead of zero-ing a drive, since one pass of zero-ing is not secure enough (certain three-letter agencies can still deduct the original contents of a zeroed harddisk, since the individual bits are not 100% truly 1 or 0, but just "mostly 1" or "mostly 0". Compare it to a lever which you can put "all the way left" or "all the way right", but usually just a swing to the other side is enough.

Comment: Weird, in OS X's Disk Utility, it asks you how many times you'd like to zero a drive when you erase it, but `srm`'s man page says it's random.

Comment: @tkbx trying to `dd` a partition you may want to fill all empty space to 0 rather than random to get a smaller compressed file later.

Comment: @Konerak I'm fairly suspicious of that. I've heard it said all over the place and I've never once seen evidence of it being possible on any remotely new harddrive (made in the past 10 years at least).

Comment: also, if you have physical access to a machine and there is no bios password, you can easily scramble the hd by overwriting the MBR with dd.

Comment: @Bartl: only overwriting the MBR/FAT will still allow certain applications to recover files from the disk, just as only deleting the files (= marking the file as deleted).

Comment: @Konerak, Re "*certain three-letter agencies*": to the contrary, in the 20+ years since [Palimpsest file recovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method) was hypothesized, there's been [no evidence](http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-gutmann.html) that anyone can recover zeroed out data.  It's a techo-superstition that does positive environmental harm, because it prevents hard disk re-use, (after paranoid users destroy their old disks with hammers and drills instead of zeroing them out).

Comment: @agc interesting read, thanks! Maybe I should have said "certain three letter agencies *might*" instead of "*can*". In theory, the absense of proof does not prove something impossible... even with Wikileaks leaking enough trade secrets... but realistically speaking you're probably right.

Comment: @Konerak, A supplemental [thought experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment): if it were possible to recover data *n* levels of deletion deep, disk manufacturers could exploit that greater data density to multiply their data resolution by *n* times.  Even if that proved commercially impractical, (let's say an *n* times palimpsest read/write head was too slow, or cost more than *n* times a conventional head), data recovery companies could afford such boutique techniques.  If the techniques for palimpsest reads were too expensive even for recovery vendors, then... (*cont*)

Comment: @Konerak (*continued*), even the TLAs would have to find budgets for it, (perhaps padded, assuming suitably covert accounting methods), so that the cost per MB would be prohibitively expensive for all but the highest priority evidence.  Multiply that cost up one more level, (given the present hypothesis that the palimpsest method would be a state secret), and therefore require some kind of evidence laundering to be a applied to domestic investigations.  At this level of cost, the profit level for faking evidence (or the lack of it) rises, especially if there's not much oversight.