# Difference between /dev/null and /dev/zero

Tags: devices

When trying to redirect to `/dev/null` and `/dev/zero`, the output it is discarded. It seems both `/dev/null` and `/dev/zero` accept and discard all input. So, what is the difference between `/dev/null` and `/dev/zero`?

Comment: `rm -f /dev/zero ; echo -n 111111111111 > /dev/zero` \*runs away\*

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Yes, both accept and discard all input, but their output is not the same:

- `/dev/null` produces **no output**.
- `/dev/zero` produces **a continuous stream of NULL (zero value) bytes**.

You can see the difference by executing `cat /dev/null` and `cat /dev/zero`.

- Try `cat /dev/null > file` and you will find an empty `file`.
- Now try `cat /dev/zero > file`, 
  while watching the size of the file (`watch -n 1 du -h file`) continuously increase. This is because reading from `/dev/zero` gives an endless stream of `\0` (null) characters.

Use `dd` to visualize the difference more appropriately:

```
$ dd if=/dev/null of=file count=10
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000276193 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file count=10
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
5120 bytes (5.1 kB) copied, 0.00090775 s, 5.6 MB/s
```

`/dev/zero` is used to create dummy files or swap.

Also visit:

- [Purpose of /dev/zero?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63238/66803)
- [Of Zeros and Nulls](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/zeros.html).

Comment: Also see http://thecodelesscode.com/case/6

Comment: Worth noting: `mmap`ping `/dev/zero` with `MAP_PRIVATE` is the "portable" way to obtain an anonymous memory mapping (in the absence of extensions like `MAP_ANON`).

Comment: Perhaps not obvious to the casual reader is just *how* `/dev/null`  produces no output: It signals EOF immediately.

Comment: Is there a device that gives all ones?

Comment: hi @AaronFranke, Oh sure!  `:-)`  Consider output of `/dev/zero` as a stream of _potential_ all-ones bytes: we just need to replace each all-zeros byte with an all-ones byte.  An all-ones byte is `377` in octal (as `printf '%o\n' $((2#11111111))` tells us); **`tr '\000' '\377' </dev/zero >/tmp/all-ones.dat `** will swiftly generate a huge pile of all-ones bytes.