# When is mandatory use /dev/zero over /dev/null for write/discard purpose?

Tags: devices, fhs

According with the `FHS` about `/dev` at:

- [6.1.3. /dev : Devices and special files](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch06.html#devDevicesAndSpecialFiles)

it contains:

```
The following devices must exist under /dev.

/dev/null
      All data written to this device is discarded. A read from this device will return an EOF condition.

/dev/zero
      This device is a source of zeroed out data. All data written to this device is discarded. A read from this device will return as many bytes containing the value zero as was requested.
...
```

Observe that both have:

```
All data written to this device is discarded
```

I read many tutorials where `/dev/null` is always used to discard data. But because both have the same purpose about writing (discard)

**Question**

- When is mandatory use `/dev/zero` over `/dev/null` for **write**/*discard* purpose?

BTW for other differences - practically mostly about **read** - we have available:

- [Difference between /dev/null and /dev/zero](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254384/difference-between-dev-null-and-dev-zero)

Comment: Why do you think it would ever be mandatory? (Well, apart from constructed cases like a chroot environment that doesn't have `null` but has `zero`, I guess.)

Comment: Perhaps mandatory for some scenarios where performance and blocking would be involved.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you're using Linux, it's never "mandatory" to redirect to `/dev/null` instead of `/dev/zero`. As you've noticed, you'll get the same result either way.

That said, you should always redirect to `/dev/null` if you're discarding data. Because everyone understands that writing to `/dev/null` means throwing the data away; it's expressing your intention.

On the other hand, writing to `/dev/zero` also throws your data away, but it's not immediately obvious that that's what you're trying to do.

Besides that, I'd be concerned whether writes to `/dev/zero` are allowed on other Unices, like the BSDs etc. I don't think `/dev/zero` is even required by POSIX, while [`/dev/null` is](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html). So using `/dev/null` for its intended purpose is maximally portable; doing anything else is sacrificing portability for no gain.

Comment: Interesting - here comes a secondary question: What was the purpose to allow write/discard to `dev/zero` if `/dev/null` offers the same approach

Comment: @ManuelJordan I don't know for sure, but probably because not allowing it would've taken extra work, while allowing it worked by default and didn't cause issues.

Comment: If I had to *construct* a reason on the fly, I'd say it would have to do with the ability to open `/dev/zero` in read-write mode. You can at least read *something* from `/dev/zero`, something you can't do with `/dev/null`.

Comment: I'll bet they actually share much of the code in the kernel drivers. The only difference between them is how they respond to reads.

Comment: @ManuelJordan: I went looking for a justification when it was implemented. I found that the kernel function for writes to /dev/zero was unified with the one handling writes to /dev/null in [this patch](https://github.com/mpe/linux-fullhistory/commit/7f2bbbe9cd7b0d23de65b969940f53bfb2dcde48) in 1993 and hasn't been touched since. The ability to write to /dev/zero seems to have been added in [this commit](https://github.com/mpe/linux-fullhistory/commit/f772a827146bb992d393de2aa84805269dc22d8e#diff-1392fcf44576b2c237e308ff0f26636d0221d410feac7cd59135058604ebe531) in October 1992 without comment.

Comment: @EgorHans I can tell you as a Linux device driver programmer, it takes more work to add the function that handles reading the data and then doing nothing with it, than to leave that function entry `NULL`.

Comment: @studog, not much more though, when you can just point to the same no-op function `/dev/null` anyway has...

Comment: @ilkkachu I was curious so I'm looking at `drivers/char/mem.c` right now, and there are different -- nope! It's the same function behind both, there's a `#define` changing the name for the zero device. Which pre-dates git, so that's as far as I'm digging.

Comment: @NickMatteo thanks for the links, in the beginning I thought the same - about historical reasons. But even with that - "without matter" what device was created before than the other - both offers the same job. I thought the answer would be about performance reasons. But seems it is not the case. Interesting this situation. Anyway we already have some standards throughout these years for them, one for reading and other for writing

Comment: @studog: I already posted links to the commit where that define was added, and to when the write_zero function was added before the define!

Answer (score 8):

There is a use case: if a program detects its stdout is directed into `/dev/null` and alters its behavior (which is not very Unix-way, in my opinion), and you don't want that.

I know only one example: `tar`. Imagine you want to ensure all files in some directory are actually readable from the disk (no I/O errors, etc.). One way to do it is to `tar` them to `/dev/null`:

```
tar -cv dir/ > /dev/null
```

But if you try it you may find that `tar` doesn't actually read the contents of the files, only the metadata (the command runs way too fast). And

```
tar -cv dir/ > /dev/zero
```

does read the files' contents (runs slower, with more disk reads).

Comment: Hngh, yep, that's a hilarious behaviour. Another way to work around it is to pipe to `/dev/null` through `cat`. Also works if you want prevent the software from detecting it's connected to a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

There is no mandatory cases, but there are use cases:

- **/dev/null**: is often used when you need to provide a file name, but you do not care about the data.

  Often this is used on `stdout`: you do not want output of a program, so you redirect the output to `/dev/null` (so it is discarded). Very convenient on scripts (and cronjob), where you check the status, but text will just confuse.

  You can read `/dev/null` to create a empty file (but other syntaxes may be better e.g. `: > empty_file_name`), or when I just want the headers of a table, but I do not want to deliver data
- **/dev/zero**: I use it when I should *physically" erase data, e.g. with `dd` command: I override an hard-disk with zeros. Zeros is never ending, so it will override all the hard disk, without having a original file (or occupy space). Alternate it is to use `/dev/random` but it will much slower.

  I do not remember I wrote to `/dev/zero` (it seems `/dev/null` has a better name).

**Note**: `/dev/zero` will continue to feed data (and it tell program that it has data). `/dev/null` instead (when used as input) just tell the program that there are no more data).

It is interesting the documentation you linked. As you see `/dev/null` is usually used to write, and `/dev/zero` to read (it according with the first case for each one listed on documentation).

In general: when we are creating a script, we may find new way to use them. It depends on what I'm doing, and what parameters are required by a specific programs. We have also `yes` command, which deliver us `y` (with a new line), when we need to feed many confirmation to programs.

Comment: I can't see a reason to write to `/dev/zero` here.