# How can I zero files out inside a VMware image file so that their space can be reclaimed?

Tags: filesystems, vmware, virtualization, disk

is there a command on Linux to remove a file but zeroing it's contents first?

so if i do, something like this:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/pacman/pkg/*
```

it would overwrite each file on that directory with 0 values, then erase it

i need it for compacting my VMware image files without creating super big file containing zeros first.

Comment: Why will a simple delete not do?

Comment: Does VMWare not support the trim/discard command? That'd save a bunch of I/O, as you'd not actually need to 0 the sectors.

Comment: @terdon because the sectors needs to be zeroed first before vmware could compact their image files..

Comment: Possibly related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63337/how-can-i-be-sure-that-a-directory-or-file-is-actually-deleted/63343#63343

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shred command can zero out a file. To do what you want, I think something like this should work

```
find /var/cache/pacman/pkg -type f -exec shred -n 0 -z {} \; \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/pacman/pkg/*
```

Comment: this one works, thanks.. my 1.8G vmdk, now become 1.5G ^^

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `shred` command:

```
shred -z -u <filename>
```

`-z` option makes file become zero, then `-u` option will delete file.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the tool `zerofree` to zero out all the blocks on disk that are unused. This can save you a significant amount of space.

This method will require that you boot into an alternative OS such as [Finnix](http://www.finnix.org/). You could also use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) which comes with zerofree installed.

#### Example

Using Finnix:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y zerofree
```

Once installed you run this tool on the entire partition like so:

```
$ sudo zerofree -v /dev/sda1
```

Then poweoff:

```
$ sudo poweroff
```

#### References

- [Compacting a VMDK (Virtual Machine Disk Format image)](http://splatoperator.com/2012/07/compacting-a-vmdk-virtual-machine-disk-format-image/)
- [zerofree website](http://intgat.tigress.co.uk/rmy/uml/index.html)

Comment: i wish i could mark "accepted" more than 1 answer..

Comment: @Kokizzu - No worries, an upvote is the best compliment!

Comment: ah but the bad part about it, it cannot be executed into a mounted partition..

Comment: @Kokizzu - correct, this is an alternative method to shred, but can work on the entire partition, whereas the other methods are essentially per file.

Comment: Ryan Finnie (the author of Finnix) tells me that Finnix now includes `zerofree` as of Finnix 107.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/clear-unused-space-with-zeros-ext3-ext4 also covers this topic (for ext3/4 filesystems).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand when you refer to zeoring.If you want to truncate a file to 0B
you can use `> filetotruncate.txt`.
For example:

```
$ ls -lh file
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 94M sep 25 17:27 file
$> file && ls -lh file
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep 25 17:28 file
```

Comment: what i mean with zeroing is overwrite the contents of the file with zeros