# How can I zero the unused blocks on my filesystem in order to minimize the compressed disk image size?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, dd, disk

If I `dd` my disk and compress the image with `lzma` or `lzo` the image is still big. The partition is 10GB used, 90GB available. But the image still around 20GB. I believe that is because I have copied many and deleted many files on that disk and the filesystem doesn't zero the unused blocks from those deletions.

How can I zero the unused blocks in order to minimize the disk image? So that dirty bytes don't add up on my image. I'm using ext4.

Comment: Please define effectively, is that different from just zeroing? Is there zeroing without having an effect?

Comment: In this context one might rephrase the question to ask how to make an image backup of a filesystem that excluded unused blocks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tool you think you're looking for is `zerofree`, as described in this duplicate question [Clear unused space with zeros (ext3,ext4)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/clear-unused-space-with-zeros-ext3-ext4), and already available in most distributions.

However, you seem to be asking how to take an image backup of a filesystem that excludes unused blocks. In this instance use [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org), as described in [this answer over on the AskUbuntu site](https://askubuntu.com/a/28499).

Comment: zerofree seems to be what I'm looking for. I will test and get back to you.

Comment: `partclone` is another option.