# Why use dd instead of cp to create bootable disk?

Tags: dd, cp, iso

Is there any difference between doing i.e. `dd bs=4M if=archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress oflag=sync` or doing `cp archlinux.iso /dev/sdx && sync`, and reason to use one over the other? (aside from the pretty progress bar in dd)

Comment: less wear on flash disk?

Comment: My (rather uneducated) guess would be that this is about writing to a block device, not a 'regular' file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days)

Comment: @A.B No, that would make zero difference.

Comment: @Panki The “magic” for writing to a block device is in `/dev/sda`, not in `dd`. `cp` can do the job just as well.

Comment: This question should state the operating system.  It is important to any answer.  Is it an old one?  Or a modern one?  Does it have block devices?  Or only raw devices?

Comment: @JdeBP I am using arch linux

Comment: When writing blocks with size 4096 bytes and bigger, there is almost no difference in speed when using modern linux systems and writing into USB devices. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931581/flashing-ubuntu-iso-to-usb-stick-with-dd-recommended-block-size/931588#931588). -- I *think* that `cat` and `cp` write blocks with 4096 bytes but the tool that is really writing to the device might do something else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One difference is efficiency, and thus speed. For example, you could get the bytes one by one and copy them to the device, with `cat` if it had the [idealized implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052892/kernighan-and-ritchie-example-on-copying-characters#25054097) or in older systems, [for example BSD4](https://gist.github.com/sinclairtarget/47143ba52b9d9e360d8db3762ee0cbf5#file-4-cat-bsd4-c):

```
cat archlinux.iso > /dev/sdx
```

In these implementations `cat` will move each *byte* independently. That is a slow process, although in practice there will be buffers involved. Note that modern `cat` implementations will read blocks (see below).

With `dd` and [a *good* block size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd) it will be faster.

With `cp` it depends on the buffer size used by `cp` (not under your control) and other buffers on the way. The efficiency lies between the idealized implementation of `cat` and `dd` with the optimum block size.

In practice though modern `cat` and `cp` will ask the system for the [preferred block size](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html): *st_blksize*. Note that this doesn't have to be the [optimum block size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492).

An analogy: it is like pouring the contents of a glass into another glass.

- idealized `cat` would do it one drop at a time.
- `dd` will use a spoon, and you define exactly how big the spoon is (system limits apply)
- `cp` and modern `cat` will use its own spoon (`stat -f -c %s filename` will tell you how big it is).

Comment: The analogy to the glass is really nice!

Comment: **This answer is completely false.** _"In theory cat will move each byte independently._" - No, it will not. `cat` reads and writes blocks just like `dd` and `cp` do. Modern `cat` (e.g. GNU `cat`) actually [asks the OS what the preferred block size is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245499/how-does-cat-know-the-optimum-block-size-to-use), for optimum speed. On my system, `cat` uses 128KiB blocks, compared to `dd` which only moves 512 bytes at a time. There's no reason to use `dd` here. And where it matters, it's slower except if you manually match the block size.

Comment: _"With `dd` and a good block size (usually related to the physical block size) it will be faster."_ - More misunderstandings; optimal block size is completely unrelated to physical block size (typically 512B, sometimes 4kB). The OS will take larger amounts of data and write it out to multiple physical blocks, no problem. The concerns for userspace applications in choosing block size have to do with 1) minimizing the number of system calls and 2) optimizing CPU cache usage. This is why `cat` uses 128KiB; large enough that the number of syscalls is small, and fits CPU caches well.

Comment: @marcelm thanks for the input. I hope the edit and the links make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I use it mainly because of the `status=progress` you mentioned; what can I say, I am impatient and need to *know* :-)

Even if you forgot to add that and started the job, you can send it a SIGUSR1 signal and it will print the current I/O statistics to stderr (which, unless you redirected it, is your terminal).